# Pimcore scheduling

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, pimcore

In Pimcore when I schedule an object to publish, it didn't work. I see that we require to enable cron job in some file. I didn't get complete details on this any where. Is there any step to enable this  process?
  Can we use scheduling as part of workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, you need to add the cron job to crontab as described in step 5 here:
https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Getting_Started/Installation.html

You need either a shell access or a control panel like cPanel or Plesk to set this up. The process is different for each operating system, but for most of the Linux distributions it means executing this command as your server user (for Debian/Ubuntu that is www-data, check what the user is for other distributions):

```
sudo -u www-data crontab -e
```

In there you have to add this line (modify the path to your console.php):

```
*/5 * * * * php /path/to/pimcore/cli/console.php maintenance
```

As said this is different for every linux distribution, but should be simple enough once you figure out how to setup a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

It worked. I am using AWS instance, followed below steps.
1) pbrun beroot (Power Broker - root privilege)
2) crontab -e
3) insert mode (i)
4) */5 * * * * php /...path../pimcore/cli/console.php maintenance
6) :wq

Can we use scheduling as part of workflow?  I have an object, after reviewer reviews, it should get published based on scheduling. Is there any way to schedule in workflow?

Comment: Thanks for posting back your solution. I don't have much experience with workflows, but I would try using an object.preUpdate event to check if the object is in the right state, otherwise I would disallow publishing. Not sure if this would work, but that's how I would try to approach that. I would also suggest you to post this as a separate question - that way there's a better chance someone else will answer.

Comment: I will try your suggestion. Thanks for the reply.